# Loop into CSV file and get specific values from headers PHP

Tags: php, regex, csv, while-loop

I'm trying to import CSV file in order to automate the candidacies insertion.

As a first step, the user imports an excel file (.xls, .xls). From file, I convert it to csv in order to exploit it better thanks to PhpSpreadSheet library.

Example of csv file : 
[image]

I would like to recover only some data columns, like **lastName**, **firstName**, **gender**, **phonenumber** .

For that, I'm using regular expressions to detect them. In every detection, I store the result in array. 
However afterward, how can I recover data from these columns ?

```
$headers = [];
if(($handle = fopen($loadedSheetName.'.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    foreach (fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';') as $key => $header) 
    {
        if (preg_match('/^(lastName)/i', $header, $matches)) 
        {
            $headers[$key] = $header;
        }

        if (preg_match('/^(firstName)/i', $header, $matches)) 
        {
            $headers[$key] = $header;
        }

        if (preg_match("/^(gender)/i", $header, $matches)) 
        {
            $headers[$key] = $header;
        }

        if (preg_match("/^(phoneNumber)/i", $header, $matches)) 
        {
            $headers[$key] = $header;
        }
    }

    $keys = array_keys($headers);
    $values = array_values($headers);

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {    
        $num = count($data);

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
        {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$headers = [];
$skip_headers = Array('lastname', 'firstname', 'gender', 'phonenumber');
if(($handle = fopen($loadedSheetName.'.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    foreach (fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';') as $key => $header) 
    {
        if (!in_array(strtolower($header), $skip_headers)) 
        {
            $headers[$key] = $header;
        }

    }


    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {    
       foreach ($headers as $key_ => $value)
       {
           echo $data[$key_] . "<br />\n";
       }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @stefo91, but with your code, I still recover all the content file :/